# how to embed vlc media player into my c# windows form app?

Tags: c#, windows

I know how to use windows media player in my app but it doesn't work for some files.I have search the web but found nothing that could be understood about using vlc in form.Could sb help me step by step to do this please?Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, only COM objects/apps with a COM interface can be embedded in a form.

Answer (score 5):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=58438

NET wrapper for VLC media player. This library allows you to use libvlc from .NET code without dll imports. Simple and easy to use for playing, streaming, transcoding of video streams. Visit the home page for more info.

Comment: what should I do after downloading the file?

Comment: After downloading file, you can read the examples on the provided links I think?